# AngularJS - ng-show with scope variable not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hide/show certain things when the orientation of the phone changes.

Here is my view:

```
<div ng-controller="ModelCtrl">
    <p ng-show="isLandscape">Landscape - {{ isLandscape }}</p>
    <p ng-show="!isLandscape">Portrait - {{ !isLandscape }}</p>
</div>
```

And here is the controller snippet:

```
    $scope.isLandscape = false;

    // Listen for orientation changes
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        // Announce the new orientation number
        switch(window.orientation) 
        {  
          case -90:
          case 90:
            $scope.isLandscape = true;
            alert($scope.isLandscape);
            break; 
          default:
            $scope.isLandscape = false;
            alert($scope.isLandscape);
            break; 
        }
    }, false);
```

I am able to alert the correct value of isLandscape on orientation change, but it seems it does not update the view, so it is always saying its in "portrait mode - true".

Comment: Also, you should use the `$window` service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are [missing a `$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
$scope.isLandscape = false;

// Listen for orientation changes
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    // Announce the new orientation number
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        $scope.isLandscape = true;
        $scope.$apply(); // <--
        break; 
      default:
        $scope.isLandscape = false;
        $scope.$apply(); // <--
        break; 
    }
}, false);
```

Once you change the value, Angular doesn't have a way of knowing that it should check whether the value has changed or not. `$scope.$apply` will trigger a digest loop which will make Angular notice that `$scope.isLandscape` has changed.

---

A better solution is to inject `$window` into your controller and add the `orientationchange` event listener to it instead. That will obviate the need for the `$scope.$apply`.

Comment: Why do we have to instruct Angular to look for the change?  If we include something like <div>{{isLandscape}}</div> in our page it will respond to changes as they occur.  Why doesn't ng-show respond to changes similarly?

Comment: @RussJackson I have updated the answer to include a version which will not need an explicit `$scope.$apply`. The `$scope.$apply` is needed since Angular will not do any dirty checking if you use native browser (or jQuery, mootools, d3, etc.) event listeners and change plain javascript objects. However, that may change with `ObjectProxies` in ES6 and Angular 2.0. Stay tuned!